# jquery slider change color of coverd area

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

i am using jquery slider i want change background color of covered area of range slider to green and rest in red and want to make slider handle position fix
any help would be greatly appreciated

```css
.slabHeight
{
    margin-top:50px;
}
#WrapperSlabSlider .ui-widget-content
{
    background:#CB4335;
}
#SlabRangeSlider label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#SlabRangeSlider .ui-slider-range .ui-widget-header .ui-widget-content { 
    background-color:#117A65; 

}

#SlabRangeSlider  .ui-slider-handle {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 3px solid #f15a23 ! important;
}
```

```html
<div id="WrapperSlabSlider" class="slabHeight">

  <div id="SlabRangeSlider">

  </div>
</div>
```

Desired Result [image]

My Output [image]